# Развертывание приложений Java на сервере

Tags: java, веб-программирование

Нужен совет новичку на Java. Во всяких технологиях, IDE... уже как-то разбираемся (в основном для desktop приложений), но про развертывание приложений на web-сервере еще много вопросов.

Основные особенности разрабатываемого приложения:

1. Должны быть две версии - web и кроссплатформенная desktop.
2. Удобство установки, использования, обновления настольной версии для пользователя.
3. Версия web должна выполняться на стороне сервера, что бы снять нагрузку с клиента, например актуально для iPad.
4. Небольшая БД, авторизация пользователей.
5. Хотелось бы не писать один и тот же код по два раза каждый раз в ходе разработки и поддержки (для desktop и web отдельно).
6. Приложение не очень сложное, предполагается развитие в сторону осуществления социальной сети между зарегистрированными пользователями, только для web-версии.

Теперь вопросы:

1. От чего отталкиваться, от desktop или web, т.е. выкладывать настольную версию на сервер или можно наоборот - заставить web-версию запускаться в Windows, Linux, Mac OS?
2. Можно ли desktop-приложение Java разместить на web, что бы оно выполнялось на стороне сервера?
3. Если web-приложение работает локально, надо запускать соответствующие сервера, что уже неудобно для обычного пользователя, нельзя ли обойтись по другому?

Comment: Дополню вопрос, если можно.
Где разворачивать свои приложения? Ну, кроме как локалхоста?
Вот написал я хелловорлд сервет со строкой хранимой в бд (извращение но все же). Куда обращатся и что делать, чтобы мой сервлет можно было показать друзьям ?

Comment: Я бы внес поправку: Куда обращатся и что делать, чтобы мой сервлет можно было показать друзьям (на их компьютерах, что бы работало без активного соединения с интернет)?

Comment: что делать с моим сервлетом и бд, чтобы можно их было просматривать через интернет у друзей.То есть, я так понимаю их нужно расположить на каком-нибудь хостинге? (познаний как все это работает у меня мало, поэтому и спрашиваю)

Т.е. написать сервлет запустить его на локалхосте это я умею и знаю как сделать.

Comment: <a href="http://hashcode.ru/users/2064/viacheslav">Viacheslav</a>, похоже либо я вас не понимаю, либо вы меня не понимаете.  
Вопрос можно ли десктоп приложение развернуть на сервере или web-приложение заставить работать локально (собрать пригодный для установки и использования обычным пользователем некий пакет приложения)? Какой вариант лучше?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Не надо ни от чего отталкиваться. Разрабатывайте общие части в виде отдельных модулей-библиотек. Так получится переиспользование кода.
2. Можно, но ни в коем случае не нужно.
3. А зачем обычному пользователю запускать у себя сервера?

UPD:

> > хороший вариант, т.е. создаем два проекта и используем общие модули? еще не понимаю как интерфейс разрабатывать, отдельно придется писать?

Ну да, делаете общую модель данных и общую бизнес логику в shared модулях и два отдельных приложения, которые эти модули используют.

> > не нужно с учетом условия выполнения приложения на сервере?

А какой смысл запускать десктопное приложение на сервере? Как вы себе это представляете? Как пользователь окно увидит?

> > не совсем еще понимаю, а как локально можно запустить web-приложение?

Традиционно веб-приложения выполняются на сервере и отображаются в 
веб-браузере пользователя + JavaScript выполняется на стороне клиента.

**UPD2**

Чтобы показать друзьям, веб-приложение надо развернуть на сервере или на своей машине и открыть к нему доступ из интернета путём настройки своей машины и роутерамодемаetc.

Если надо показать без доступа к интернету, то придётся все необходимые сервера устанавливать у них, либо использовать какие-то portable-версии этих серверов, которые работают без установки.

Можно в одну директорию затолкать все нужные сервера (тот же tomcat не требует установки) и сервер БД, если требуется. И напишите скрипт, чтобы всё это запускать одним движением руки.

Comment: 1. хороший вариант, только вот опыта нет, хотели по-проще сделать, хотя наверное только усложняем
2. не нужно с учетом условия выполнения приложения на сервере?
3. не совсем еще понимаю, а как локально можно запустить web-приложение?

Comment: Не могли привести примеры реализованных приложений или инструментов, подсказать, например, названия проектов (в том или ином IDE) для web и desktop, как их можно связывать... Чего-нибудь, или навести на учебник, на примерах проще понимать.

Comment: <li>А какой смысл запускать десктопное приложение на сервере? Как вы себе это представляете? Как пользователь окно увидит?</li>  
Смысл такой, запускать десктопное приложение на сервере в качестве web-приложения, для упрощения разработки, чтобы не плодить один и тот же код. Или все таки это не возможно?  
  
<li>Традиционно веб-приложения выполняются на сервере и отображаются в веб-браузере пользователя + JavaScript выполняется на стороне клиента.</li>  
Возможен ли вариант, что сервером является сам клиент и приложение отображается на его же броузере?

Comment: Да откуда там возьмётся один и тот же код? Будет два разных приложения, одно в виде war/ear для развёртывания на сервере и одно в виде jar. Попытка объединить их в одно - это будет не упрощение, а усложнение.

Такой вариант возможен. Только это редко бывает нужно. Не в вашем случае точно.

Comment: Сам изначально за отдельную разработку этих двух версий, однако ТЗ говорит обратное - один код, одинаковый интерфейс.

Comment: Да плюньте на ТЗ и делайте нормально. Эти ТЗ составляют безголовые.

Answer (score 0):

> Хотелось бы не писать один и тот же код по два раза каждый раз в ходе разработки и поддержки (для desktop и web отдельно).

Прочитайте про [шаблон MVC](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-View-Controller), это поможет вам разобраться, каким образом избежать дубликации кода, когда необходимо иметь несколько различных представлений для одного и того же функционала (веб-приложение, десктопные приложения на различные ОС, мобильные платформы и т.д.)

Если вкратце, вам необходимо разделить на отдельные независимые модули безнес-логику и визуальное отображение.

> Можно ли desktop-приложение Java разместить на web, что бы оно выполнялось на стороне сервера?

Сервер — это просто компьютер, который умеет отвечать на HTTP-запросы HTTP-ответами. Он сможет выполнять те же функции, что и ваш домашний компьютер.
Вам будет нужно принять HTTP-запрос, при его обработке вызвать функции, которые вы называете "desktop-приложение Java" и затем вывести результат работы пользователю через HTTP-ответ. Таким образом вы выполните код на стороне сервера.

Comment: Спасибо за советы, но задача уже решена. Как и предполагалось, поставленное некомпетентным руководством ТЗ является противоречивым и вообще не правильным. Слава Богу, я уже давно ушел из этой конторы.