# Оффлайн запуск web-приложений

Tags: java, веб-программирование

Добрый день! Пишем web-приложение на Java. Задача усложняется тем, что приложение должно работать в оффлайн режиме.
Варинт отдельно разработать настольную версию не подходит. Остается решить вопрос, можно ли заставить его работать в автономном режиме?
Есть вариант подготовить пакет содержащий само приложение (такое же, которое лежит на web-сервере, за исключением, настроек, неполной БД) и все необходимые web-сервера.

Какие есть варианты решения?

Настройка всего этого при установке, подводны камни в ходе эксплуатирования на Windows (XP, 7), Linux, Mac OS?

Дополнение к вопросу [Развертывание приложений Java на сервере](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/32810/%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-java-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5)

Приложение должно работать в онлайн и оффлайн (с некоторыми ограничениями, например не ведется статистика) режиме одинаково.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможности HTML5 (локальное хранилище данных в частности) позволяют создавать web-приложения работающие автономно и синхронизирующиеся при наличии связи с сервером. Яркий тому пример - надстройка к GMail для автономной работы.

Стоит подумать, нужна ли вам именно тут именно Java. Например средствами Adobe Flex можно создать приложение которое сможет работать как в браузере, так и в виде десктопного приложения (через AIR).

Comment: HTML5 еще вроде броузерами слабо поддерживается?  
Часть кодов приложения должна быть скрыта от злоумышленника.

Comment: HTML5 поддерживается хорошо, но для скрытия кода  - это не для javascrip....