# Выбор платформы PHP или Java?

Tags: php, java, веб-программирование

Выбираем, пробуем разные платформы для разработки web-приложения (тонкий клиент, важно для платформ iOS), у которого должна быть кросс платформенная оффлайн версия. Запутался уже совсем, думал на Java писать, похоже, для нашего несложного приложения вполне подходит PHP (его и изучать проще), на PHP реализовано немало проектов и такие высоконагружные как ВКонтакте.
*Главная сложность нашего проекта* состоит в том, что онлайн и оффлайн версии должны иметь один код и один интерфейс (чтобы не пришлось их отдельно писать).

Решение видим следующие:

1. *Писать десктопное Java приложение и развертывать его на сервере.*
   Для запуска настольной версии на Windows, Linux, (Mac OS?) нужно только JVM установить.
   На сервере можно как апплет или JWS оформить (вопрос относительно тонкого клиента придется решать?).
2. *Писать web-приложение на JavaEE, работающее на GlassFish например.*
   Настольную версию предлагается делать следующим образом: запускать локальный сервер GlassFish, на котором выполняется наше приложение. Похож на какой-то кустарный метод? Вопрос удобства для пользователя - установка и настройка сервера, возможные подводные камни?
3. *Писать на PHP.*
   Схож с пунктом 2, с серверами только вроде попроще?

Вопрос бредовый, тем не менее хотелось бы узнать ваши комментарии, какие еще есть варианты?
Предыдущие темы:
[Язык программирования для Web-приложений](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/30976/%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-web-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9)
[Развертывание приложений Java на сервере](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/32810/%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-java-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5)
[Оффлайн запуск web-приложений](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/33160/%D0%BE%D1%84%D1%84%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA-web-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Посмотрите на Adobe Air, он позволит написать кросплатформенное приложение не только на все десктоп платформы, но и на iOS, и веб часть на флеше.

Comment: хотя php backend скорее всего понадобится тоже.

Comment: единый код для различных платформ не лучшее решение. хорошо, если просто будет медленно работать (в сравнении с нативными приложениями) и больше весить, а в проектировании сложных систем больше риска появления лагов и всевозможных ошибок.

Answer (score 4):

Дополню ответ [@ArtFeel](/users/1565/artfeel). Adobe Flex + AIR в вашем случае, возможно, единственное разумное и доступное решение. Ниже делюсь личным опытом разработки решения с аналогичными требованиями.

Вы получите из одного и того же кода практически:

- Десктопный клиент (AIR).
- Клиент для браузера (Flash).
- Клиент для коммуникаторов (Flash).

Но будут определенные ограничения архитектурного плана.

Web-сервис в данном случае можно будет писать на чем угодно - его задачей будет только прием и возврат данных, вполне сойдет и PHP, если есть ограничения по времени на освоение технологий. Лично я бы выбирал между REST-службой на Java (Jersey) и REST-службой на Ruby (Ruby On Rails), оба варианта позволят быстро и просто сделать сервис для выполнения CRUD операций, HTTPS на Java поднимается за 5 минут. В качестве транспорта данных -  просто XML или JSON (я бы выбрал второй).

Клиент будет "толстым" - вся логика приложения должна быть сосредоточена в нем. Кроме того, в клиенте организуете абстрактный слой доступа к данным, через который приложение будет читать-писать. Для конкретных источников данных пишите соответствующие реализации: для связи с web-сервисом, для локального desktop-хранилища, для локального хранилища на мобильных платформах. В зависимости от внешних условий (с какой платформы запущено и есть ли связь с сервером) приложение включает конкретную реализацию слоя доступа к данным.

Comment: лучше используйте JSON, это практически REST-стандарт, к тому же он быстрее парсится и куда лучше поддерживается по сравнению с технологией XML

Comment: @DmitryMaslennikov, вопрос 11 года ) Ответ в любом случае потерял актуальность.

Comment: да, только сейчас заметил) хотя некоторые вполне просматривают такие вопросы через поиск. что же касается JSON, то ситуация за это время только еще больше приблизила его к стандарту.